# How to get cart products in email template magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using abandoned cart extension, which is sending the normal reminder email to the customer. Now, I want to add products in the email template.

How can do this? Can anyone help?

Comment: Add product image in which email template like order,shipment. @vinod kumer

Answer (score 1):

In the email template you can use the layout code to add any .phtml file and doing code on code phtml file

example.

```
 {{block type="core/template"  area="frontend" template="productemail/allproducts.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

load your cart products:

```
 $customerId = 1; // your customer ID
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)
        ->loadByCustomer($customer);

    if ($quote) {
        $collection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
        if ($collection->count() > 0) {
            foreach( $collection as $item ) {
                echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
                echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
                echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
                echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
                echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
                echo "<br />";

            }
        }
    }
```